# Mage 2 MIgration Tool Failure

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, magento-2.0.7

I'm attempting to migrate a store from GoDaddy to Nexcess.  The tool is failing on migrate:settings for reasons Nexcess can't resolve.  They've (been really really great) only done migrations locally moving from localhost to localhost.  I'm not doing that, and am not sure the Migration Tool can handle what I'm asking?

[image: The result]

The thing is, sassyboutique.com isn't our site, but our hosts doesn't think the problem is on their end.

My code from the config.xml file:

```
<source>
    <database host="107.xxx.xxx.xxx" name="fxxx" user="fxxx" password="fxxxx"/>
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="173.xxx.xxx.xxx" name="fzzz" user="fzzz" password="fzzzz"/>
</destination>
```

I've verified the info with Nexcess basically just the IP to connect to and the DB info.  I'm using the IP addy's that both hosts are providing.  On the local side with Nexcess I've also used 'localhost' and 127.0.0.1 but all fail.

I can find no instances of this happening.  Anyone have any idea whats causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're running the script on the new Nexcess server and hoping to migrate the data from the database still running on your old server.

The fact the error message contains sassyboutique.com is likely just because that's the hostname being detected for the IP. If you try `nslookup {old server ip}` from the new server, that's probably the value that will be returned for name. Either way, it's probably not an issue you need to worry about.

The most likely problem is that your old host is blocking public access to MySQL (normally port 3306). If you run `nmap {old server ip}` from your new box you should get a list of open ports. My assumption is that this won't include MySQL meaning you likely can't get access to it from outside the old server.

Assuming my long list of assumptions is correct, your best bet might be to:

- use mysqldump on the old server to create an sql file for the DB
- create a new empty db on the new server
- transfer the dumped sql file from the old server to the new server (via ssh or ftp)
- import the sql into the new empty db
- update your migration config to use the new db for source
- run the migration with both dbs on the same server